# Как вывести последний символ элемента списка в Питоне

Tags: python, python-3.x

Как вывести последний символ элемента списка в Питоне

Comment: А в чем загвоздка?

Answer (score 2):

Если я правильно понял вопрос, то просто нужно использовать индекс -1 это будет последний символ последнего элемента.

```py
...
i = int(input('Введите номер элемента > '))
print(arr[i][-1])
```

Comment: Это последний элемент, а не последний символ последнего элемента.

Comment: Да спасибо, исправил, тут просто не сказано какого именно элемента, поэтому предположил, что автор поста имел ввиду последнего.

Comment: @Эникейщик разве правку принял не автор ответа? Что же, прошу прощения. Не так давно на SO, ещё не со всеми обычаями ознакомился.

Comment: Эта была правка, которую я подтвердил.

Comment: @Gari ок. Тогда прошу прощения. Иногда правки подтверждают другие, особо не вникая.